# PostScript Path Combine

Tags: postscript

I have just begun learning PostScript in order to produce graphics for LaTeX and I have no idea how to combine a path with itself so the stroke only affect the outer border of the drawn shape. My code is as follows:

```
/black { 0 0 0 1 setcmykcolor } def
/gold { 0.02 0.17 0.72 0.05 setcmykcolor } def
newpath
  % the center is 1/2w and 1/2h
  /cx { 1200 2.0 div } def % center-x
  /cy {  600 2.0 div } def % center-y
  /r  {  600 9.0 div
               4 mul
             2.0 div } def % star's radius
  cx r   0 cos mul add
  cy r   0 sin mul add moveto
  cx r 144 cos mul add
  cy r 144 sin mul add lineto
  cx r 288 cos mul add
  cy r 288 sin mul add lineto
  cx r  72 cos mul add
  cy r  72 sin mul add lineto
  cx r 216 cos mul add
  cy r 216 sin mul add lineto
closepath
gsave
gold fill
grestore
1 setlinewidth
black stroke
```

When the stroke is drawn, the lines crossing the shape are drawn. I would like to know if there is a way to only have the outer border of the shape stricken and not the inner lines. i would rather not have to calculate where the lines forming the star intersect, *i.e.* keep 5 lines instead of getting 10 smaller ones.

Note also, that I am learning PS as-is and am not wanting to use external programs (read Illustrator and the like). The purpose of this question is to built up my knowledge of PostScript.

Comment: It sure would be nice if there were an operator to do this. `maskpath` would be a good name for it.

Comment: +1 @luserdroog, I too wish there were a `maskpath` operator. Care to compose one?

Comment: I'm not sure I have the skill to do it. I never could get my Weiler-Atherton implementation to work. I tried some experiments with `clippath` `reversepath` `clip` and `eoclip` but I wasn't able to get the "outside" of the shape. But I discovered that `clip` followed by `clippath` will get you the Wyatt-Warnock "reduced" shape. But it's tessellated, not seamless; so it doesn't seem to help here. :(

Comment: My comment here is wrong. `clip clippath` does *not* give you the reduced shape. I was misinterpreting the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest would be to do the stroke first and then the fill. You may want to double your linewidth as doing this effectively cuts the lines in half.

```
%...
closepath
gsave
  2 setlinewidth
  black stroke
grestore
gold fill
```

Comment: I like your solution; however, it is not optimal.

Comment: Agreed. But the only other option I can see is something like Weiler-Atherton; where you walk the path and check all those intersections. On the bright side, the radial symmetry means you only need one, and the rest are rotations.

Comment: @Minustar Much later, I figured out how to transform from the criss-crossed 5 pointed star to a series of `lineto` calls for just the outer edge. You have to find the intersection point between adjacent points. https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.postscript/c/nQyNUS_grZI/m/bLUI-Qn4CAAJ (if you have a custom CSS plugin for your browser, use `html-blob{white-space:pre}br{display:none}` to see the indentation).

Answer (score 1):

PostScript is missing an anticlip operator, which should restrict painting to outside the current path. There is `clip`, which restricts painting to inside, but that doesn’t help with this problem.

As previously suggested, you could `stroke` at double linewidth, and then `fill` white, but if you want to paint this on top of something else, that strategy obscures whatever is below.

Or you could make the star a little bigger (I suspect, but haven’t checked, by `currentlinewidth 2 5 sqrt 2 mul 5 div add sqrt mul 2 div`), but that would only look right if `1 setlinejoin`.